# It is ok to create IAM object per user for AWS Javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm working on S3 files uploader. Users can login to my web app and upload files to their own bucket. I don't want to use third party authentication services (like FB, G+ etc), because user is already authenticated. So, it is ok to create IAM object per user and hard-code AWS KEY nad AWS SECRET KEY in the html?

Or maybe there is a way to attach to the request a signature (policy) which is generated by backend? Eg:

```
s3.putObject({
  Bucket: 'bucket',
  ...,
  signature: ...,
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you heard of the Simple Token Service? Sounds like that's what you're looking for

Answer (score 3):

That is probably not a good way to go, IAM is designed for authentication to AWS services and should not be used for application authentication, where Amazon Cognito would be more adequate.

That said, if you want to use IAM users but not creating one policy per user, you can use policy variables: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/PolicyVariables.html

Comment: Authenticating users would be more appropriate than relying on a generic application level access key and secret key like EvaporateJS does.  As Julio suggested, Cognito is the way to go.  You can use your own authentication backend, you are not forced into FB, GOOG etc ... Have a look at https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxBVEDL5Z8JKAC/Use-Amazon-Cognito-in-your-website-for-simple-AWS-authentication and https://identity-demo.aws-emea.info/cognito for a JS example